# C# Lucene.net で　検索結果（文字列）をソートした状態で取得したい

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

C# Lucene.net で　検索結果（文字列）をソートした状態で取得したいのですが
サンプルを紹介してもらえませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

本家SOに類似する内容の質問と回答がございました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489307/how-to-sort-the-result-in-lucene-net-in-c

手元に環境がなく検証はしておりませんが参考になるかと思います。